# How to filter data in FirebaseRecyclerOptions

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm using FirebaseRecyclerOptions from Firebase-ui. I want to show list of book. In `bookQuery` I've fetched my desired books list but here I need to filter more my book list. I wanted something like **select * from book_table where ownerID="my_id" and category="biography"**. After searching I found that we can't use multiple orderByChild in a single query. Is there any way I can apply my additional condition in the data I fetched from `bookQuery`?

```java
Query bookQuery= FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Books")
                .orderByChild("ownerID")
                .equalTo(user.getUid());

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Book> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Book>()
                        .setQuery(bookQuery,new SnapshotParser<Book>() {
                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public Book parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                                    Book book=snapshot.getValue(Book.class);
                                    return book;

                            }
                        }).build();
```

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. So in your case that could be something like `"category_ownerID": "scifi_uidOfOwner"`. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I want to do this without adding the extra property as my Book class has already 15 property. I want to use your first proposed method **1. filter most on the server, do the rest on the client**. How can I get list of all book's of a particular user? I can do this using `ValueEventListener` but I there any way when I'm using firebase-ui ?

Comment: Your query should already be getting the books of the specific user: `.orderByChild("ownerID").equalTo(user.getUid())`. FirebaseUI doesn't have a built-in ability to do further filtering on the client though, so you'll either have to hide all items that are not in the selected category, or write your own adapter.